# How to add Edges to object using Loops

Tags: edit-mode, edges, shortcut, proportional-editing

Using this tutorial to learn how to make Christmas Tinsel (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2YFHXJDWJk). At 9:08, they add edges to the object using an "Edge Loop" I believe in order to use proportional editing to give the object a curve like so:

[image: Youtuber]

I am unaware how to do so. The closest I can get to this (Image below) using the subdivide option by right clicking.

[image: My screen]

Comment: Ctrl R is the shortcut to add edge loops, then use the mouse wheel or the "+" or "-" of the numpad to increase or decrease the amount of edges. It's in the Edge menu > Loop Cut and Slide, or Ctrl E

Answer (score 3):

Please watch that tutorial with caution, at the left bottom side you can clearly see that he uses Loop cut shortcut Ctrl+R, this makes edge in the middle of your mesh and by scrolling your mouse wheel, you can make any number of cuts you want